# ios Javascript OnClick function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have loaded an HTML file from server and displayed that in `UIWebview`, where it contains an `OnClick` Function in that file, when the user OnClicks, i will get one Video URL. I want to open that video url in **iOS** `videoplayer`. how can i do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a javascript function which returns the URL when the "Get Video URL" button is clicked like this:

```
function getVideoURL() {
  // do processing to fetch the actual video URL here

  window.location = "http://www.domain.com/videos/1";
}
```

and button handler is set as something like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:getVideoURL();" class="btn-image GetVideo">&#32;</a>
```

then you will have to provide implementation for UIWebView's following delegate method in your view controller class:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

After this you can use the relative path from the java script request

```
 request.mainDocumentURL.relativePath
```

inside the delegate to refer to the URL returned from the Java script method. You can use the fetched URL to open iOS video player and play the video as follows:

```
MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString: strurl]];
moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;  
[moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.

But we need to know what `onClick` function does exactly? 
Does it return video URL directly?
Or it modifies HMTL to display that video URL?

If it returns videoURL directly:

```
NSString *videoURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById("yourElementID").click();"];
```

If it doesn't, you need to parse the HTML for videoURL after calling onClick function.